# Can I use the Google V8 Engine to build Windows GUI apps?

Tags: javascript, v8

I was looking at the V8  engine whch says it can compile JavaScript code. Is there a way I can use it to make Windows applications?

Comment: You don't need V8 for windows 8 apps: [Tutorials](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-windows-store-apps-with-html5-jump-start), [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx)
If you want to write executable GUI application for older Windows systems, I suggest using Qt Webkit - this ships with a whole browser. If it should be just a command line application, you can indeed use V8. But this is JS only! (No DOM, no GUI).

Comment: Yes, it "complies" js code, but it doesn't "compile js code to an exe file".